# $f(c)\int_{c}^{b}g(x)dx = g(c)\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous over $[a,b]$

How to show that there is $c \in [a,b]$ such as : 
$f(c)\int_{c}^{b}g(x)dx = g(c)\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? What theorems have you been studying before attempting this problem? Are there any you think might be useful? This isn't a "do my homework for me" site, so we often ask that you share your thoughts and work so far before we make suggestions.

Comment: Just to make it clear: you are not told to _find_ such a $c$, you are just told to prove that one exists. What theorems do you know that concerns functions and their values with the conclusion that "there exists a $c$ between the end points such that..."? One of them is bound to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider

$$H(x):=(\int_a^xf)(\int_x^bg).$$

Comment: Thank you, that helped:
$H$ is continuous and derivable over $[a,b]$, and $H(a)=H(b)=0$

So according to Rolle's theorem, there exists $c$ such that
$$H'(c)=f(c)\int_c^bg-g(c)\int_a^cf=0$$